# Typical network socket timeout

Tags: java, sockets, timeout

I'm interested to know, what is the typical network socket timeout value, used in production today.

I'm currently using 30 seconds in our Java application, but would like to hear what other using, especially for Internet communications.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no common socket timeout value. It is application/environment dependent. I use 10 minutes, but this value doesn't give you any information, I think.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "typical" socket timeout.  Rather you should chose the timeout(s) according to the application requirements.  Issues such as:

- Is there a user waiting for the response?
- Is a timeout a likely event?
- Does setting a "too long" timeout tie down lots of resources, or delay processing?
- Does setting a "too short" timeout result in wasted processing when waiting a bit longer would have given results?
- Is there a keep-alive mechanism ... so that you can distinguish between (say) network failure and the remote server taking a long time?

The best strategy is probably to pick some intuitively sensible values, and then tune them.

Comment: Thanks, this list quite helps to approximate the value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no common value, it heavily depends on the application (how many messages are sent per hour, the more messages being sent the lower your timeout can be) and the network used (longer timeout over the internet than over a local network).

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb you can use double the expected response time for the transaction. But there is certainly no such thing as a 'typical' timeout.